# Normalizing 4x4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 4x4 matrix $A$.  It does not satisfy the following condition,

$AA=1$

and $1$ is the identitiy matrix or diagonal of 1's.  I must normalize matrix $A$ such a way that the condition is satisfied, say

$BB=1$

and

$B=XA$.

Therefore $XAXA=1$.

Find $X$.  Is it possible?  $B$ is a matrix.

Comment: Take $A = 0$, then no matter what $X$ you pick, $XAXA = 0 \ne 1$. So no, it is not possible in the general case.

Comment: If $A$ is singular, this is not possible because $XAXA$ would be singular too. If $A$ is nonsingular, you may just take $X=A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            A.A = 1
Therefore,    A = 1/A.
Now, from  XAXA = 1, we have
          XX.AA = 1
i.e.,        XX = 1
Therefore,    X = 1/X
```

*I Hope this suffice your query.
Thanks...!*